# Custom ActionFilters In WebApi 2

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2, custom-action-filter

I have two `ActionFilterAttribute` - `ValidateModelStateFilter` and `LoggingFilter`.

In `ValidateModelStateFilter` I have :

```
 public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (!actionContext.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest, actionContext.ModelState);
            base.OnActionExecuting(actionContext);
        }
    }
```

for chacking ModelState. And In `LoggingFilter` I have:

```
public override void OnActionExecuted(HttpActionExecutedContext actionExecutedContext)
    {
        LogRequest(actionExecutedContext);

        base.OnActionExecuted(actionExecutedContext);

        LogRensponse(actionExecutedContext);
    }
```

I want log every request and every response, even if it contains any ModelStateError.

Now, my problem is: When ModelState is not valid, it Returns me ErrorResponse as expected but Logging filter does not execute.

Here is WebApiConfig.cs Register :

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Web API configuration and services
        // Configure Web API to use only bearer token authentication.
        config.SuppressDefaultHostAuthentication();
        config.Filters.Add(new HostAuthenticationFilter(OAuthDefaults.AuthenticationType));
        config.Filters.Add(new AuthorizeAttribute());
       // config.Filters.Add(new ValidateNullFilter());

        config.Filters.Add(new ValidateModelStateFilter());
        config.Filters.Add(new LoggingFilter());


        config.Services.Replace(typeof(IExceptionHandler), new GlobalExceptionHandler());

        // Web API routes
        config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```

Do you have any suggestions how can I make it work?

Answer (score 0):

In your Logging filter you need to implement both OnActionExecuting and OnActionExecuted

Before your action is called,  the OnActionExecuting method is called where your can log a request. 
After your controller action has run, your action filters' OnActionExecuted method will be called where you can log a response.